# Providing the persistent volume of standard type for statefulSet fails

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, storage, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-statefulset

I get the following errors in the cloud console after the deployment of a statefulset (bitnami/redis) with the PVC:

> (combined from similar events): Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "standard": googleapi: Error 503: Internal error. Please try again or contact Google Support. (Code: '-295147017683364552'), backendError

How this problem can be fixed? Do I really need to contact the support?

Comment: are u doing this in google kubernetes engine?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google API Error Codes](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors):

> **HTTP:** 503 **RPC:** UNAVAILABLE    **Description:** Service unavailable.
>
> Typically the server is down.
> Clients may [retry](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors#error_retries) on 503 UNAVAILABLE errors with exponential backoff. The minimum delay should be 1s unless it is documented otherwise.

It looks like some temporary instability with the cloud console API.

I'd recommend contacting [Google Cloud Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en) to assess what's happening:

- On your console click on the question mark (?) in the top-right part of the screen, then click in "Get Support".

Your only other option would be to wait a few hours and trying again.

The nature of the error does not hints as being an issue with the StatefulSet deployment.

If I can help you any further let me know in the comments.